# Accumulate variable in different scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see my code:

```
function foo() {
    var h = "start";
    $.each(some_array_of_objects, function() {
        var name = 'middle';        
        h += name;
    });
    h += "end";
    alert(h);
}
```

I expect to see accumulated string in my alert but instead of this I got string with a lot of **[object Object]** strings. Is that possible to accumulate **h** variable in above way WITHOUT USING global variables?

Comment: This is most likely because `$(this)[0]['name']` is an array. Can you post the value of the `some_array_of_object` variable.

Comment: Please post the code to the object that `this` refers to.

Comment: You're not using "global variables". `h` is only available within the scope of `function foo()`.
Now, could you show us the contents of `some_array_of_objects`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is absolutely hasn't matter here. See mine updated code

Comment: I'm not sure what the jQuery constructor is doing there. Don't you want just `this.name`? Try to rewrite it as a simple for-loop without any jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use jQuery to loop through arrays / object, just use a `for` loop for arrays, and a `for-in` for objects.
This will work in your case:

```
//Assuming the input array is something like this:
some_array_of_objects = [[{name:'ABC'}],[{name:'I am a name'}],[{name:'Look at me!'}],[{name:'foo'}],[{name:'bar'}]]

function foo() {
    var h = "start";
    // Loop through the array.
    for(var i = 0; i < some_array_of_objects.length; i++){
        var name = some_array_of_objects[i][0].name;        
        h += name;
    }
    h += "end";
    alert(h);
}
foo(); //Returns: "startABCI am a nameLook at me!foobarend"
```

Comment: OK, thanks, but what is the problem with my code? Is there some restrictions on variable scope?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that question.